# Why is my test method returning null when I used Mockito's when?

Tags: junit, mockito

I am trying to mock, using Mockito 1.9.x, the following code which happens to be in the advice method of a Spring AOP join point

```
protected void check(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
   final Signature signature = pjp.getSignature();
   if (signature instanceof MethodSignature) {
      final MethodSignature ms = (MethodSignature) signature;
      Method method = ms.getMethod();
      MyAnnotation anno = method.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
      if (anno != null) {
        .....
}
```

Here is what I have for the mock so far

```
ProceedingJoinPoint pjp = mock(ProceedingJoinPoint.class);
Signature signature = mock(MethodSignature.class);
when(pjp.getSignature()).thenReturn(signature);

MethodSignature ms = mock(MethodSignature.class);
Method method = this.getClass().getMethod("fakeMethod");
when(ms.getMethod()).thenReturn(method);

....
```

So I have to create a Method instance using a fakeMethod() within my test class since you cannot mock/spy final classes. Using the debugger I see that the method instance is good after the call to "this.getClass().getMethod("fakeMethod");" but within my check() method, method is null after it executes the line "Method method = ms.getMethod();" which causes an NPE on the very next line.

Why would my method object be non-null in the test case but null in the method I am testing when using the when().thenReturn()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is using the `signature` returned by `pjp.getSignature()` and not `ms` where the mock `MethodSignature` has been added. Try:

```
ProceedingJoinPoint pjp = mock(ProceedingJoinPoint.class);
MethodSignature signature = mock(MethodSignature.class);
when(pjp.getSignature()).thenReturn(signature);

Method method = this.getClass().getMethod("fakeMethod");
when(signature.getMethod()).thenReturn(method);
```